# How to get the first video id by using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the first video id from YouTube, so I try to use `BeautifulSoup`.

I think I can find   to get the video id from the href.

[image]

I get the result is `None`

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


  url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=spider"
  request = requests.get(url)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
  testVideo = soup.find(id="thumbnail")
  print(testVideo)
```

print function show `None`.  Why ?

Comment: I think you need `request.content` instead of `request.text`, because  `request.content`  gives you the source code

Comment: But pint `request.text` can see the video id, anyway I try `request.content` , testVideo is sill None.